# Can I redirect block storage devices to each other?

Tags: block-device, storage

Obviously what I'm about to describe is better handled by rsync or cp, but...

Say I have two drives on my computer. Could I make one a perfect image of the other with the following command? Would files on sda be accessible on sdb through the file system?

```
cat /dev/sda > /dev/sdb
```

My inclination is that each device could (potentially) be too different from the other for a blind write like this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Much better way to copy disk to disk is to use `dd`:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

But this will work well only if `sda` is smaller or equivalent by size to `sdb`. The same is true about the files on `sdb`.

If you want to have files on smaller `sdb` use `rsync` with some filter (to be sure you will sync successfully the files from `sda` to `sdb`)